# Stored Procudure In Hive

Tags: hadoop, stored-procedures, hive, hiveql, bigdata

I have millions of data in my Hive table. I want to execute **set of Sql statements (Stored Procedure)** in Hive. I searched on the internet what i found is there is no way we can use something like stored procedure in Hive. I want to know whether it is really impossible and what are the other way i can achieve this in **Hive**.

Comment: Although it's not possible to have stored procedures in Hive yet, there are plans to implement this functionality in the future (https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HIVE-3087)

Comment: can i implement using pig script ? i don't know if it is possible or not i am asking.

Comment: I've never used Pig, but maybe you could use HPL/SQL (http://www.hplsql.org/doc)